# Google Maps API Geocoding - Polish adresses have no Zip code?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I just discovered something really weird, Google Maps API cannot retrieve Zip code for Polish addresses:

- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform

On the link above try typing any address based in Poland, it never shows Zip code. Is this some kind of a bug in Google Maps? Here are some addresses you can try:

- Korotyńskiego, Warsaw, Poland
- Arbuzowa, Warsaw, Poland
- Kraków Główny, Kraków, Poland
- etc...

Comment: Some countries don't have zip codes. Does Poland use zip codes?

Comment: Yes, they have Zip codes, and they use them normally as any other country with zip codes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes_in_Poland

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it. The full geolocation response is:

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "result" : {
      "address_components" : [
         {
            "long_name" : "Korotynskiego",
            "short_name" : "Korotynskiego",
            "types" : [ "route" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Ochota",
            "short_name" : "Ochota",
            "types" : [ "sublocality_level_1", "sublocality", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Warszawa",
            "short_name" : "Warszawa",
            "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Warszawa",
            "short_name" : "Warszawa",
            "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "mazowieckie",
            "short_name" : "mazowieckie",
            "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Poland",
            "short_name" : "PL",
            "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
         }
      ],
      "adr_address" : "\u003cspan class=\"street-address\"\u003eKorotynskiego\u003c/span\u003e, \u003cspan class=\"locality\"\u003eWarszawa\u003c/span\u003e, \u003cspan class=\"country-name\"\u003ePoland\u003c/span\u003e",
      "formatted_address" : "Korotynskiego, Warszawa, Poland",
      "geometry" : {
         "location" : {
            "lat" : 52.2012304,
            "lng" : 20.9733135
         },
         "viewport" : {
            "northeast" : {
               "lat" : 52.2025793802915,
               "lng" : 20.9746624802915
            },
            "southwest" : {
               "lat" : 52.1998814197085,
               "lng" : 20.9719645197085
            }
         }
      },
      "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png",
      "id" : "157d3685cf7ab9663b31c02997a6be85126b688a",
      "name" : "Korotynskiego",
      "place_id" : "ChIJkR5vE7PMHkcRrh2X0p0jCsA",
      "reference" : "CmRbAAAARsIh09J0e2bLB6y7N6EVfQgCkzmCkg3ObnXJra7Hm6xc16A7CppIiJwcQoiiAnsCpRGrQD6OoGWhxE6JGYlytCOlGHRKcCtChbIqEEaCDUW6bsEyQLgCTY0m3ojohzjrEhAdYdlYCTFvw2MB65eSGhewGhROyWxAnDh-PgYPSHSr7h-L1qWRKA",
      "scope" : "GOOGLE",
      "types" : [ "route" ],
      "url" : "https://maps.google.com/?q=Koroty%C5%84skiego,+Warszawa,+Poland&ftid=0x471eccb3136f1e91:0xc00a239dd2971dae",
      "utc_offset" : 120,
      "vicinity" : "Ochota"
   },
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

I don't see a zip code in there. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes_in_Poland) Poland does have postal codes.

Comment: Thank you for the replay. Could this be some kind of a bug in Google Maps?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a data issue. If you search another address close to the first address mentioned in your post, for example reverse geocode for 52.201801,20.978833, you will see that addresses in response have a postal code:

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3D52.201801%252C20.978833

Also, I believe postal codes are supported only for street_address types, the route type results, that seems to be in your examples, will likely come back without postal codes. Imagine that one route can overlap different postal codes, in this case geocoding service won't return any postal code.

If you specify the complete address with street number and street name and don't get a postal code, that should be a data issue.

In this case you should report a data issue following this support documentation:

https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3094088

I hope this helps!